# how to override an attribute in the object?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

please help solve the problem.

have an object:

```
class Product:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I create a new object:

```
class Book(Product):
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  #???????
```

I need to override the attribute active. that is, to attribute always been active=True

at the same time I can not change the Product since I do not have access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can use save() method in your model or you can use pre_save() signal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted